# How to determine which element fired on .keyup jquery method call?

Tags: jquery, element, typing

For example:

```
  $('.input-xlarge').keyup(function(element) {
              element.parent().parent().removeClass("error success");
          });
```

**Scenario:**

I have many input fields under class .input-xlarge, they are colored green or red depending on success state after form is submitted. (non-ajax form)

Now I want it to be more user friendly - as field state is returned back from the server my field keeps glowing red until next submit with valid input is initiated.

**What is required:**

Therefore after user submitted form, received some fields - some in valid, some in invalid state I want field to be neutral decoration whenever user starts typing inside.

**What does not work:**

From the code I provided I expect:

1. to trigger event for any input field with class .input-xlarge whenever user starts typing.
2. Indicate which input field exactly requires changing of css decoration(removing css classes) to neutral white.

**Unfortunately I can't seem to extract the actual input element which triggered .keyup event. Is it possible to do this?**

As you can see I know the exact navigation towards the css element afterwards but the root object ends up with an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'parent'
```

[image]

Comment: I am not quite sure how to apply it in my situation. It is not event handler but is just a method to trigger focus? Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Aubergine you can read more about `this` in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Inside a function, you can use `this` to get the element who triggered the function. Use this:

```
$('.input-xlarge').keyup(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("error success");
});
```

The first parameter in the function is the event. An other way would be to use currentTarget on the event object (which is the same as `this`):

```
$('.input-xlarge').keyup(function(e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).parent().parent().removeClass("error success");
});
```

Also, don't be affraid to use `console.log()`. Using it in the case would have show you that `element` was an event.

Comment: Competition is tough :-) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Aha! I use alert more often for trivial cases like this. But it only shows me [Object object], now tried console and indeed it is event!

Answer (score 3):

you can use `this` inside the event handler to refer the element to which the handler was registered to - in this case the input element.

The first parameter to the event handler is the `event` object, in the event object you can use `event.target` to target the actual element which triggered the event and `event.currentTaget` to refer the element in which the handler was registered.

```
$('.input-xlarge').keyup(function(event) {
    $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("error success");
});
```

Read more about [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, when not using a selector as specific as a class (such as a $('#form').change) you can pass the event to the callback function like so:

```
    $('#SomeForm').change(function (event) {        
            if (event.target.id === "SomeElementId") {
            // do whatever you need. 
            }
     });
```